# In Unity, the camera and directional light are not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the directional light or main camera is clicked on, it just shows a dot(image below). I want to be able to see them, hence be able to control them. I am new to Unity hence any help will be much appreciated! The version of unity I am using is 2019.3.0f5

[image: Image of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting with `Rect Tool`

Double click to zoom in to your object and select the `move tool`

[image: Gizmos]

Edit: And to show the `Camera` and `Light` click `Gizmos`

[image: Unity Tools]

Edit 2: weird, i think someone/something changes the default Gizmos setting? try look at `Gizmos`'s dropdown, make sure the icon is on

[image: Gizmos Setting]

Comment: Thank you, but sadly that did not make any difference.

Comment: hmm, try my 2nd edit. If still doesn't work, i am sorry i have no other idea

Comment: Hi, it still didn't work. I reinstalled unity and somehow the problem is fixed. Thank you for the help :)